# Perfect Square for Trig Substitution

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I start off with this perfect square and I end up having to use two different trig subs depending on the way the square is made.

Original: $3-2x-x^2$

--Option A--

= $-x^2-2x+3$

= $-(x^2+2x-3)$

= $-(x^2+2x+1-3-1)$

= $-((x+1)^2-4)$

= $-(x+1)^2 + 4$

$4- (x+1)^2$ -> use $a^2-x^2$ trig sub

--Option B--

= $-x^2-2x+3$

$-x^2-2x = -3$

$x^2+2x+1 = 3+1$

$x^2+2x+1 = 4$

$(x+1)^2 = 4$

$(x+1)^2 - 4$ -> use $x^2-a^2$ trig sub

I can understand that both options can be changed by distributing a subtraction sign. Which method is better to create a perfect square in regards to trig sub ?
No matter which method I use for trig sub, will I get the same answer ?

Comment: In method B, what you did does not seem right to me. In the second line of Option B, you just put 3 on other side of equality. Your method A looks good to me. As a rule of thumb, you can always check LHS and RHS. If they are not the same thing, an error was made.

Comment: My math book shows method A while symbolab shows method B. Im kinda torn between the two.

Comment: I agree with Rob. Option B doesn't quite make sense. It looks like you are setting the original polynomial equal to zero in order to move the 3 to the other side.

Comment: Just look at the result.  Option B is the negative of Option A and is wrong.  You didn't write the left side of the equality in the first line.  If you had, you would see the second line is wrong.